# JavaScript - module pattern - problems with adding divs

Tags: javascript, module

I'm trying to understand a module pattern in JavaScript. I've taken a basic skeleton from a tutorial and tried to adapt it to my needs. There's a button that should add a div with some text.

Here's the JavaScript part:

```
// The module
var s,
    myArticles = {

    settings: {
        articleList: "#article-list",
        articleClass: ".article",
        articleIndex: 0
    },

    init: function() {
        // kick things off
        s = this.settings;
        var articles = document.getElementById(this.settings.articleList);
        this.createArticle();
    },

    createArticle: function() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class", this.settings.articleClass);
        div.innerHTML = "Article" + this.settings.articleIndex;
        articles.appendChild(div);
        this.settings.articleIndex +=1;
    }
};
```

HTML part:

```
<body>
    <h1>My articles</h1>
    <div id="article-list"></div>
    <button onclick="myArticles.init()">Add Article</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

CSS Part:

```
.article {
    weight: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Would you help me get it work?
Also, in the settings section, originally the values were surrounded by $( ). It threw errors for me so I removed them.

Thank you.

edit: this is the tutorial I was referring to:
https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/

Comment: Link to the original tutorial would help as there are several module patterns

Comment: You have referenced `articles` in the `createArticle` method, but declared it as a local variable in `init`. `articles` will be undefined in the context of `init`

Comment: I thought it would be local to the whole module not just init. Rule of the thumb is to avoid global variables, isn't it. I thought the best place to declare it would be in settings but I can't quite get the syntax right.

Comment: No its local to the function. If you want it local to the module, then set `this.articles = document.getElementById(..)`

Comment: I addition, remove the leading . in settings.articleClass. You don't need a leading . when adding the class name to an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different issue with the code above:

- The $() which you removed was referring to JQuery
- div.setAttribute("class", this.settings.articleClass); won't work properly as your setting the class to the query selector `.article` rather than the class `article`
- articles is local to init but you are trying to access it in createArticle

You'll need to make something like the changes below:

JS:

```
var myArticles = (function () {
    var s, articles;
    return {

        settings: {
            articleList: "article-list",
            articleClass: "article",
            articleIndex: 0
        },

        init: function() {
            // kick things off
            s = this.settings;
            articles = document.getElementById(this.settings.articleList);
            this.createArticle();
        },

        createArticle: function() {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("class", this.settings.articleClass);
            div.innerHTML = "Article" + this.settings.articleIndex;
            articles.appendChild(div);
            this.settings.articleIndex +=1;
        }
    };
}());
```

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <h1>My articles</h1>
    <div id="article-list"></div>
    <button onclick="myArticles.init()">Add Article</button>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: This is also a better example of defining a module in JS. You can have 'private' methods and variables within the anonymous function, and 'public' members can be exposed by returning an object from the function containing those members; as shown here.

Comment: Thanks. I've got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: Sorry mix of JQuery/Vanilla JS was messing it up should work now. Note: If your trying it in JS fiddle you'll need to change `var myArticles =` to `window.myArticles =` to make the module global so it can be seen by the JS in the click event

Comment: Got it. I should have removed # from before article-list

Comment: Awesome :) please set the answer as correct if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do something like this and just noticed your articles variable is not set for the 'createarticles' you need to make 'articles' a public variable or get it again inside of the 'createarticles' function

```
var myArticles = (function(){
var s;
var articles;
//any methods here are private
return{ //anything in return method is a public function
   settings: {
       articleList: "article-list",
       articleClass: ".article",
       articleIndex: 0
   },

   init: function() {
       // kick things off
       s = this.settings;
       articles = document.getElementById(this.settings.articleList);
       this.createArticle();
   },

   createArticle: function() {
       var div = document.createElement("div");
       div.setAttribute("class", this.settings.articleClass);
       div.innerHTML = "Article" + this.settings.articleIndex;
       articles.appendChild(div);
       this.settings.articleIndex +=1;
   }
};
})();
```

Comment: Had to edit it because i also noticed an issue with the 'articles' variable, its set to be local to the init function so creatarticle() function wont see it, that may be your issue.

Comment: The  braces closing  settings should be  ended with a , not ;. Otherwise your solution is identical to the  other one.  I get the error mentioned in the comments to the other answer: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: Got it. I should have removed # from before article-list

Comment: oh, haha glad you figured it out. I'll update my answer to reflect.